# Remove hash in URL using htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

In Previous my application was single page application. so we used id's in the URLS.
Currently we have changed as seperate pages. but our site URL is in external site. So we have to redirect the URL lines in the htacces file

> www.mydomain.com/#news/

to

> www.mydomain.com/news/

how to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^#/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

This should remove the `#` from your URL. Just make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Once you're happy that the rewrite is working, you can change `R` to `R=301`. **Don't** do this beforehand.